# OIDC: should the provider have the same address as the issuer?

Tags: oauth2, openid-connect

I'm using [Coreos OIDC](https://github.com/coreos/go-oidc) library for Go. When setting up an OIDC config (coming from `PROVIDER_URL/.well-known/openid-configuration`), I'm getting this error:

```
Could not initialize OIDC provider:oidc: issuer did not match the issuer returned by provider, expected "PROVIDER_URL" got "ISSUER_URL"
```

[... because of a library check.](https://github.com/coreos/go-oidc/blob/8ae1da518bd4d9d5a5909090a184af30f336436d/oidc.go#L124)

Should the provider have the same address as the issuer?
Is that check part of the RFC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the requirement is stated in the provider configuration section of the [specs](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html#ProviderConfig) (emphasis mine):

> **OpenID Providers supporting Discovery MUST make a JSON document available at the path formed by concatenating the string /.well-known/openid-configuration to the Issuer**. The syntax and semantics of .well-known are defined in RFC 5785 [RFC5785] and apply to the Issuer value when it contains no path component. openid-configuration MUST point to a JSON document compliant with this specification and MUST be returned using the application/json content type.

It also goes on to mentions that:

> The issuer value returned MUST be identical to the Issuer URL that was directly used to retrieve the configuration information. This MUST also be identical to the iss Claim value in ID Tokens issued from this Issuer.

In practice I'm aware that a few of the mainstream providers such as Microsoft doesn't stictly follow this pattern but you'll have to take it up with them, or consider the workarounds given by the OIDC library.